# How to use GetMap-Service by gmapping

Tags: ros, navigation, service, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using gmapping to create a map. To this point everything works fine.

Now I want to call the GetMap-Service to receive the map for further investigation:

```
#include <nav_msgs/GetMap.h>

ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<nav_msgs::GetMap>("map");
nav_msgs::GetMap srv;

  if (client.call(srv))
  {
    ROS_INFO("Service GetMap succeeded.");
  }
  else
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Service GetMap failed.");
    return 1;
  }
```

But when running this node I always get "Service GetMap failed."
I added gmapping to "find packages" in CMakefile and to build & runtime dependencies in package xml.

What's my fault?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227834/how-to-use-getmap-service-by-gmapping/) by [Alex1209](https://answers.ros.org/users/25356/alex1209/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the documentation, the service is called `dynamic_map`. Try that one.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alex1209](https://answers.ros.org/users/25356/alex1209/) on 2016-03-02**:
so you mean to use `gmapping::dynamic_map` instead of `nav_msgs::GetMap`as service? And include `#include <gmapping/dynamic_map.h>` ? Can you post a link to documentation please?
If I do so I get the fault "gmapping/dynamic_map not found"

**Comment by [Alex1209](https://answers.ros.org/users/25356/alex1209/) on 2016-03-03**:
I now found the documentation you talk about I think. Is it [this](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/gmapping/html/classSlamGMapping.html)?
so I in cluded `#include slam_gmapping.h` but when i `catkin_make` this file cannot be found. :(

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-03-04**:
http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping